# Column not found:

Tags: laravel

```
public function AddWishlist($id)
{
    $userid = Auth::id();
    $check = DB::table('whishlists')
        ->where('user_id', $userid)
        ->where('whishlists', $id)
        ->first();

    $data = ['user_id' => $userid, 'product_id' => $id];

    if (Auth::check())
    {
        if ($check)
        {
            $notification = ['messege' => 'already added whisahlist', 'alert-type' => 'error'];

            return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
        }
        else
        {
            DB::table('whishlists')->insert($data);
            $notification = [
                'messege'    => 'Suucessafully added whisahlist',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            ];

            return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $notification = array(
            'messege'    => 'At first login your account',
            'alert-type' => 'error'
        );

        return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
    }
}
```

**Problem**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'whishlists' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `whishlists` where `user_id` = 1 and `whishlists` = 37 limit 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logic will be to change

```
->where('whishlists', $id)
```

with

```
->where('whishlist_id', $id)
```

if its not working, Please show us the table whishlists

Note:

if $id is the id of the wishlist, i think this line should be reviewed :

```
$data = ['user_id' => $userid, 'product_id' => $id];
```

because it set 'product_id' with the whishlist id